# 'undefined' when using attr method in d3.selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a 'd3-select' package for changing my plot, and I'm blocked by this strange error.

it works just fine when I used 'attr' method after selectAll('path'), but it breaks when I used it on selectAll('line'). And I figured out that 'attr' on selectAll('line') receives nothing.

## Code

```
const paths = this.$gPlot.selectAll('path');
console.log('paths =', paths);
paths.attr('d', path => console.log(path)); // there's two path elements

const lines = this.$gPlot.selectAll('line');
console.log('lines =', lines);
lines.attr('y1', line => console.log(line)); // there's three line elements
```

## Result on console

[image]

I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you supply a function to functions like `attr()`, the first argument of the function is the data that is bound to the element, which has usually been previously assigned by calling `data()` on the group. It is not the SVG element itself.

In your case, there is data bound to the paths, but not the lines, so you are getting `undefined` on the lines when calling the function. To get the reference to the SVG element via the function, use:

```
lines.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
})
```

You have to use a full function, not shorthand, for the `this` to be correctly scoped

Comment: Actually I just remembered - you can use inline functions, as the third argument supplied to the function is the collection of nodes. So `lines.each((d, i, nodes) => console.log(nodes[i]))` will also work